# Symmetric encryption with partial knowledge of key

Tags: symmetric

While reading [Laurent Bussard's thesis](http://www.eurecom.fr/en/publication/1519), Section 4.5.1, p91 (p119 of the pdf) I wondered about the following paragraph (emphasis mine):

> the prover first picks a random symmetric key $k \in_R \{0, 1\}^m$ and uses
>   it to encrypt her private key $x$ according to a publicly known
>   symmetric key encryption method $\mathcal{E} : \{0, 1\}^m \rightarrow \{0, 1\}^m$. This leads
>   to $e = \mathcal{E}_k (x) \in \{0, 1\}^m$. *Note that as in every encryption scheme,
>   only the knowledge of both $e$ and $k$ allows to compute the private key $x = \mathcal{D}_k (e)$.*
>
> ...
>
> In the $i$-th interaction, the prover releases either $k[i]$ or $e[i]$
>   ...
>   Note that $k[i]$ (resp. $e[i]$) denotes the $i$-th bit in the binary representation of $k$ (resp. $e$)

It appears to me that only an ideal cipher achieves the required property: wouldn't knowing some bits of $k$ and the complementing bits of $e$ reveal some information on $x$ in any real-world encryption scheme such as AES? (See also property 4.3(b) in the same thesis).  Could one estimate how much information of $x$ is leaked upon multiple executions of this protocol (where an ephemeral $k$ is chosen each protocol execution)?

(Note that in section 4.7.3 he actually uses a one-time pad for encryption, which does appear to have the required property).

Comment: Why are "complementing bits" of $e$ relevant? If the leaked information depends on known bit positions of $e$ and $k$ being disjoint you either have an OTP or a very bad block cipher.

Comment: I may have phrased that awkwardly. With complementing bits I mean that for every index $i$ the protocol reveals either $k[i]$ or $e[i]$, so if $k[i]$ is not leaked, than $e[i]$ is leaked. I don't know if this is relevant at all, I just observed this from the protocol description.